# Drupal upload images folder

Tags: image, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

How can I set Drupal to upload images into a folder by year and months (eg.: sites/default/files/images/2013/07/myimage.png).

I'm moving my website from Wordpress, which automatically do this (it creates a new folder for years and months).

Is possible to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please help me... anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely can do this with Drupal.

Install the [FileField Paths module](https://drupal.org/project/filefield_paths). Node tokens, for example, the node creation time will be available to use as a token.